# Login page keep clearing my textboxes in login.

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

I have this problem. When i want to login on my php page, it just clears the textboxes and nothing else.. i've been trying to fix this problem but i can't find a solution. Here's the code:

```
<?php
include_once ("db.php");
include_once("session.php");

$username=$_POST['uporabnisko']; 
$pass=$_POST['geslo'];

    if ((!empty($username)) && (!empty($pass)))
    {
        $pass=sha1($pass); // zakodiramo geslo

        /*$query=mysql_query("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$pass'");
        $username=mysql_real_escape_string($username);
        $pass=mysql_real_escape_string($pass);*/

        $query = sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'",                   
                    mysql_real_escape_string($username), mysql_real_escape_string($pass));

        $result=mysql_query($query);

            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) // preveri, če je uporabnik v bazi 
            {
                $user = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                $_SESSION['prijavljen'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['id_user'] = $user['id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];

                echo   // preusmeri na index.php
                ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Uspešna prijava!')
                window.location.href='index.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
            }
            else
            {
                echo 
                ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Napačno uporabniško ime /geslo..')
                window.location.href='prijava.php'
                </SCRIPT>");
            }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 
        ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.alert('Niste izpolnili vseh polj!')
        window.location.href='prijava.php'
        </SCRIPT>");
    }
?>
```

I don't know what could be wrong..

Comment: Can session_start() be missing here? I mean I don't see what is in session.php, but check whether you have your session active at the places you do want that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **;** after each of your Javascript lines. You need

```
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Napačno uporabniško ime /geslo..');
                window.location.href='prijava.php';
                </SCRIPT>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your include_once tags to require_once tags to ensure that your scripts are actually being included.

You should also use mysqli or prepared statements at the very least for your login to protect yourself from SQL Injection attacks.

To redirect the pages, you can use the header function in php

```
$result=mysql_query($query);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) // preveri, če je uporabnik v bazi 
        {
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $_SESSION['prijavljen'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['id_user'] = $user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];

            header("location:index.php");
         } else {
         echo("Napačno uporabniško ime /geslo..");
         header("location:prijava.php");
         }
```

Try these changes, they might help